# Is an .msi file an executable or an input file to an executable?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056090/156458 says

> The command to install an MSI is the MSI itself - they're executable
>   files.

But I thought an .msi file is an input file to Windows Installer (which is an executable). 
So is an .msi file an executable or an input file to an executable?

Is the command to install an MSI also `MSI`, or `msiexec`?

Is Windows Installer `msiexec`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

.msi files are not by themselves executable.  They need to be associated with msiexec.exe to work.  They are a package that can contain .exe files along with the data required to set up the environment for the executable.

If you disable the windows install service .msi files will not work.

Comment: Thanks. Is the command to install an MSI also MSI, or msiexec?

Is Windows Installer msiexec?

Comment: The command to install an MSI is msiexec.exe and it has several cmd line options.  It is part of the windows installer service, but not the only part. For example msi.dll is also part of the windows installer service.

Comment: This answer is correct. The other one on Stack Overflow isn't. Well, its partially correct.

Comment: @TNT: Thanks. What is `msi.dll` used for? What uses it?